# Only binary format input

Tags: java, swing, validation, binary, jtextfield

I have a small issue. I am creating my own small program that includes a Binary calculator. I have the calculator created, but what I want to do is limit the input of the user in the `jTextField` only to 1s and 0s. If that is not possible than when the user enters anything else besides 1s and 0s , the button that is used to convert (calculate) from binary to decimal to get automatically disabled when the user inputs anything else besides 1s and 0s.

I have tried looking in other questions, but I don't think it is a duplicate. If it is, I apologize.

Anyone any idea?

EDIT:

The code below is my Bin to Dec converter method used in the actionPerformed method of the button:

```
void BinToDec() {
        if (tfNumber.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No values entered");
        }
        decList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            int binary = Integer.parseInt(tfNumber.getText());
            if(binary >= 0) {
                int temp = binary;
                do {
                    decList.add(temp % 10);
                    temp /= 10;
                } while(temp > 0);
                w = 0;
                x = 0;
                sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < decList.size(); i++) {
                    w = decList.get(i);
                    x = (int)Math.pow(2, i);
                    w = w * x;
                    sum = sum + w;  
                }
                result = Integer.toString(sum);
                tfBin.setHorizontalAlignment(tfBin.CENTER);
                tfBin.setText(result);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Decimal for the binary number " + tfNumber.getText() + " is: " + result, "Decimal representation of a Binary number", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                lblBin.setText(String.valueOf(result.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "").trim()));

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't enter a correct value! Please enter only a positive number", "Error - Incorrect Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't enter a correct value! Please enter only a positive number", "Error - Incorrect Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: The same `JTextField` is used when a user enters a number and wants to convert it to Binary format, so the check must be performed in the above method

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @JavaLearner I have edited my post and added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `keytyped` event of textfield. Let's say you have a textfield named `jTextField1`..then you can set its `keytyped` event as :

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    char c=evt.getKeyChar(); //get input from text field character by character
    if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '1') || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) 
    {
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

The above code will allow you to input only `1's` or `0's` or `backspace` or `delete` and will block any other input..

Hope this solves your problem..It works for me

Comment: Well my problem is that this same field is also used for inverse calculation(decimal to binary). And I will have to input this method in the method for the binary to decimal only

Comment: But as per the question, your requirement was to allow only input of 1s and 0s : **what I want to do is limit the input of the user in the jTextField only to 1s and 0s.**

Comment: Yes you are right :) I forgot to complete with all the details. But if I create a separate method and include it in the actionPerformed method of the button it should work right ?

Comment: I think it will not work because the above method records the keytyped event i.e. it checks each key as the user types within the text field..So I think it will no work on button action..

Comment: For decimal what you can do is that in the above code change `1` to `9`..then it will allow only input between 0 to 9 but again user can input value other than 0 or 1 in binary to decimal conversion case

Comment: Well that is why I asked above for example if a user enters other values than `1` or `0` the button created to convert from binary to decimal to become disabled/unclickable

Comment: @Tanata05 : It is not a good act as, in hindsight, the question more and more to expand. But the input to check for validity is best done in a `Field1KeyTyped event` and only there you can set the `convert button` to enabled or not.

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast and moskito-x : Thanks I have tried your answer and I got it working all fine :)

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast and moskito-x: I have done that and it works when I enter for ex. `110123` but when I delete all that and if I enter for ex. `110101` the button stays disabled. I then added the `else` statement and set the the field to `setEnabled(true)`. Now after entering '1101' the button is enabled, after typing '110123' the button gets disabled, and after adding `1` or `0` after the latest number looking like this `1101230` the button gets enabled again.. and it shouldn't. Should I raise another question for this or ?

Answer (score 3):

I think a `JFormattedTextField` should do the job: see [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for details.

```
MaskFormatter binaryMask = MaskFormatter("#####"); //each # represents one valid character input
binaryMask.setValidCharacters("01"); // specifies that only the charaters '0' and '1' are allowed as input

JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(binaryMask); // creates the test field using the binary mask
```

Comment: @Icewind so where you have entered #s I should do the same or ?
You said in your comment: //each # represents one valid character 
So I should write 2 # or ? Sorry, but I didn't fully understand you :)

Comment: where is here the test for `0s` or `1s` ?

Comment: the method setValidCharacters(Sting) of the MaskFormatter specifies which characters are allowed.

Comment: @Icewind can you please check and advise me on how to implement the Formatted Text Field in my code above? Also I think there isn'the method .setText for the formatted TF ? or ? Because it gives me errors for my above code

Comment: @Tanata05 well if you want to allow 10 character in your input you should use 10 `#`. There is a `setText()` method for the Formatted TF

Answer (score 3):

In order to validate the data on a Swing-component you should use the **`InputVerifier` Class**.

Check it out at the [API Docs for `InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).

To find out whether the given number is binary you can do:

- *A numerical check*

  ```
  public boolean isBinary(int number){
      while (number != 0) 
          if(number % 10 > 1) return false;
          number /= 10;
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```
- *A string check*

  ```
  public boolean isBinary(String number){
      char[] ary = number.toCharArray();
      for(char c : ary) {
          if(!(c == '0' || c == '1')) return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

Comment: where is here the test for `0s` or `1s` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `DocumentFilter` class to filter the input on a `JTextField`.

First, create the custom `DocumentFilter` class:

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class BinaryFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                             String string, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(string);
        for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
            if (ch!='0'&&ch!='1') {
                buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
    }

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                        int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) fb.remove(offset, length);
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

Then, implement it into your `JTextField`

```
JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
Document inputFieldDoc = inputField.getDocument();
BinaryFilter tmpFilter = new DocumentFilter();
((AbstractDocument) inputFieldDoc).setDocumentFilter(tmpFilter);
```

Comment: where is here the test for `0s` or `1s` ?

Comment: @JamesHunt I will try to see if it works. Isn't any other more simpler way to do it ?

Comment: @moskito-x in the insertString function, it checks if a character is a 0 or 1, if it is it is deleted from the box.

Tanata05, Icewinds answer seems easier to implement.

Comment: and now can one insert the `s` or not ?